# How to compress/merge a table that shares the same vaule in column A, and append all data to the end row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to find a way to go from [Original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJBgc.png) into a more [Compressed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrwLm.png).
I have column A which will always have "Corp Name", followed by a list of contact information. This issue is for every contact it ends up creating a new row. so a single "Corp Name" might repeat 4 times.

column A is a Corp name
column B is a persons name
column C is a phone

```
 - If column A "Corp Name" is the same as the one right above it

 - then move the next three cells and append cells to the end

 - else skip to next row
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a perfect case for Power Query.  So, you must be running Excel 2010+ and not Excel for Mac.

Let's call your Original Table, Table1.  By the screenshot that you provided, it appears that it is already an Excel Table with headers.  To use Power Query, you need to bring that table into the Query Editor.  Click anywhere inside of the table, then go to the Data tab and choose From Table/Range under Get & Transform Data.
[image: navigating to power query]

This will bring up the Power Query Editor.
[image]

I will first step through how to implement the solution below and later take you through how it works.  If it is interesting to know the steps in creating it, make a comment and I can circle back with more details. For now I presenting the finished solution.

Start by renaming Table1 in Query Settings on the right side to Table2.  This will make it easier to load back into your worksheet.

Next, click Advanced Editor in the Home Tab:

[image]

Now select the existing script and paste this script over it:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Corp Name", type text}, {"persons name", type text}, {"position", type text}, {"Phone", type text}}),
   // get a count of how many rows are assigned to each Corp & merge this with the orginal Table1 (with changed types)
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Corp Name"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows", {"Corp Name"}, #"Changed Type", {"Corp Name"}, "Grouped Rows", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
   // expand it out except for Corp Name, so that the Count of rows is now part of the Table2
    #"Expanded Grouped Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Grouped Rows", {"persons name", "position", "Phone"}, {"persons name", "position", "Phone"}),
   // unpiv the columns you want to replicate - there are three and that is important, so I will make it a variable in the script
    columnsToUnpiv = 3,
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Expanded Grouped Rows", {"Corp Name", "Count"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
   // now add an index that will modulated and then used to assign field names - Must be started from zero because of modulation
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
   // now divide it by the number of columns that you are unpivoting, so that it puts the same number next to each field that is part of the same row in Table1
    #"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, columnsToUnpiv), Int64.Type}}),
   // now, use the Count to create an index for each field in Table1 then add 1 to align to the target table numeration
    #"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Integer-Divided Column", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], [Count]), type number),
    #"Added to Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Inserted Modulo", {{"Modulo", each _ + 1, type number}}),
   // now concatenate the Attribute which contains the field name to the Modulo index then clean out the 1's because your example did not want that and get rid of the helper columns
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added to Column", {{"Modulo", type text}}, "en-GB"),{"Attribute", "Modulo"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Merged Columns","1","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Merged"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced Value",{"Count", "Index"}),
   // now Pivot it back into the shape you wanted
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Merged]), "Merged", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

You can then choose Close and Load To and select where you want to place Table2 which contains the result you are wanting.  Here is an example of the output:

[image]

You can copy/paste the Power Query (M language) script above, but just in case you are actually going to flatten more than the 3 columns of data, then the script above will have to be built for that purpose.  Note the line that says "**columnsToUnpiv = 3,**": this is a critical line. If you are going to do more than 3, you need to change this to reflect the number of columns that you will flatten.

But that is not the only thing that must be changed.  If your field names are different from your example, the script must follow that.  So, it is better to take a step-by-step rebuild of the script above.  Unfortunately, the automated script writing that comes in Power Query requires some modifications to get you to the result that you are seeking.  So, with that, here is an overview of how the solution above was created:

1. Ingest the table using Table/Range under the Data Tab
2. In the Power Query Editor, **select the Corp Name** and **click Group By** in the Home tab.
3. Now click **Merge Queries** from the Home tab and select **Table2**.  Click **Corp Name** in both the upper and lower table and OK. This will produce a line of script that you will have to edit by hand. You need to replace this:

= Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows", {"Corp Name"}, **#"Grouped Rows"**, {"Corp Name"}, "Grouped Rows", JoinKind.LeftOuter)

with this:

= Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows", {"Corp Name"}, **#"Changed Type"**, {"Corp Name"}, "Grouped Rows", JoinKind.LeftOuter)

4. Now **Expand** the **Grouped Rows**.  Unselect Corp Name.
5. Select **Corp Name** and **Count** and then choose **Unpivot Other Columns** in the Transform tab.
6. Choose **Add Index** starting **from 0**, under the Add Column tab.
7. Select the **Index** column and choose **Integer-Divide** in the **Standard** dropdown under the Transform tab. Divide by the number of columns that you want to unpivot - this was 3 in your example.
8. In the Add Column tab, choose **Modulo** in the **Standard** dropdown. Select **Use Values in a Column** and choose **Count**.

[image]

9. Click the Modulo column and then choose **Add** in the **Standard** dropdown under the Transform tab.
10. Click on the **Attribute** column and then the **Modulo** column (in that order) and then choose **Merge Columns** in the Transform tab.
11. Now click on the **Merged** column and choose **Replace Values** in the Transform tab. Replace 1 with "" and click OK.
12. Click on **Count** and **Index**, then press the DELETE key to remove them.
13. Now click on **Merged** and choose **Unpivot** from the Transform tab. Select **Value** and **Don't Aggregate** and click OK.
14. Choose **Close and Load** and decide where you want to save Table2.

You're done.